# String splitting with backslash

Tags: regex, r

I have a string

```
mystring <- "\"3.825"
```

I just want the 3.825 out of that.

I have tried:

```
mystring <- strsplit(mystring, "\")# (error after completing with 3 double quotes)

mystring <- strsplit(mystring, "\\")# (error: invalid regular expression '\', reason 'Trailing backslash')

mystring <- strsplit(mystring, "\\\\")# (returns the string unchanged and unsplit)
```

Not sure what else to do

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
  sub('"', '', mystring)
  #[1] "3.825"
```

You can wrap it with `as.numeric` to convert it to numeric.

There is no backslash in the string.  You can check it by printing.  It is the escape character for `"`

```
cat(mystring, '\n')
#"3.825
```

Try `'"'` on R console

```
 '"'
#[1] "\""
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an escaped quote, not a backslash and if **that** is your string, there is no need to use regex.

```
> mystring <- "\"3.825"
> substring(mystring, 2)
# [1] "3.825"
```